# How to get something from server using SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I need to create method, which can request to server and return answer. But if I use SignalR, I can run server's method and server will run client's method. But how I can create something like this template?

```
public Response Request()
{
    //???
}
```

Comment: You need to do something and you know SignalR can help you with it but you don't know how? Did you think about reading a SignalR tutorial?

Comment: I have task to implement this method. I read a lot, but I found nothing.

Comment: Documentation, tutorials and samples all available, not to mention plenty of youtube videos as well. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I use SignalR, I can run server's method and server will run client's method.

If you'd like to invoke hub method from .NET client application in c#, you can refer to the following code snippet.

```
try
{
    HubConnection connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl("http://localhost:61262/chatHub")
    .Build();

    await connection.StartAsync();

    var mes = "hello";

    await connection.InvokeAsync("SendMessage", "Consloe Client", mes);

    // await connection.StopAsync();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

    Console.WriteLine("Can not communicate with server now, please retry later.");
}
```

Hub method

```
public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
{          
    await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
}
```

Besides, to setup Hub and client, please refer to the following articles.

- [Use hubs in SignalR for ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-2.2)
- [ASP.NET Core SignalR .NET Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-2.2)